# Pygame | Почему не работает?

Tags: python, pygame

В чем проблема? Я писал через Pydroid на андроид. Только начинаю программировать
[image: Фото ошибки]

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = player_img
    self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
```

я понимаю, что там написано. Я не понимаю, что не так

Comment: может вы использовали пробелы и табуляцию в одном отступе одновременно? Если вы делаете отступы, то вы вправе выбирать как вы их делаете - либо через пробелы, либо через табуляцию, но не смешивайте эти способы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неправильный отступ.

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.image = player_img
            self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
```

Помните, что в `python` очень большую роль играют отступи.